# Should I `browserify` all files then `concat` them for my gulp pipeline? Or the inverse?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I'm starting to break out a Javascript client library in `index.js` and have an additional file that I'm now doing a `require` for at the top.

```
...
require("./other_file")
...
```

Then my `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
function compile(watch) {
  var bundler = watchify(browserify({
    entries: ['./src/index.js'],
    debug: true,
    sourceType: module,
  })
  .transform(babelify));

function rebundle() {
    bundler.bundle()
      .on('error', function(err) { console.error(err); this.emit('end'); })
      .pipe(source('build.js'))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
  }

  if (watch) {
    bundler.on('update', function() {
      console.log('-> bundling...');
      rebundle();
    });
  }

  rebundle();
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to `concat` all the files I'm going to need and then browserify that larger `concat`ted file or just `browserify` the main file and the `require` will just work?

(I followed [the gulpfile example here](https://gist.github.com/danharper/3ca2273125f500429945))

Comment: There's no need to concat. Browserify will track down all of the modules you require and build out a single bundle.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Feel free to answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to concat. Browserify will track down all of the modules you require and build out a single bundle.

> browserify will recursively analyze all the require() calls in your app in order to build a bundle you can serve up to the browser in a single  tag.

[source](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browserify)

Comment: This is definitely true 99% of the time.  I have, however, come across a few circumstances where a library, especially those involving Emscripten, included some wizardry to detect the environment and then do things that confuse Browserify.  But it's an extreme edge case, in which I end up just using gulp-concat.